# EARLIER Function not working in DAX - ATR of Stocks

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, stock, moving-average

I am making ATR34 column in PowerBI in which I have a table that consists of Stocks, Date, High, Low, Close, PrevClose and Series (contains Equity,future).
I have made a calculated column of ATR from the High Low Close and Prev Close. I need to calculate the MA of 34 days of ATR calculated filtered by Stocks and Equity.

For that I am first calculating the Daynumber filtering Stocks and EQ; then 34 days and making an average of it.
However when i am using the below mentioned code in DAX EARLIER function is not working and i am unable to calculate it.

I am beginner in POWERBI.

```
DayNumber =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ('Table','Table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] )),
    FILTER('Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] )),
    FILTER('Table'[EQ] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] ))
)

Another Caulcated Measured Column : 

FirstDateOfRange34 =
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    FILTER ( 'Table','Table'[DayNumber] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[DayNumber] ) - 34),
    FILTER('Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] )),
    FILTER('Table'[EQ] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] ))
)

Another Calculated Measured Column : 
ATR34 =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'Table'[ATR] ),
    FILTER ( 'Table','Table'[Date] >= EARLIER ( 'Table'[FirstDateOfRange34] ))
    FILTER ('Table','Table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] ))
    FILTER('Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] ))
    FILTER('Table'[EQ] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off. [COUNTROWS](https://dax.guide/countrows/) expects a single table argument, not three arguments and [FILTER](https://dax.guide/filter/) needs a table for the first argument, not a column.

Try this intead:

```
DayNumber =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] )
            && 'Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] )
            && 'Table'[EQ]    = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] )
    )

FirstDateOfRange34 =
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[DayNumber] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[DayNumber] ) - 34
            && 'Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] )
            && 'Table'[EQ]    = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] )
    )
)

ATR34 =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'Table'[ATR] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Date] >= EARLIER ( 'Table'[FirstDateOfRange34] )
            && 'Table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] )
            && 'Table'[Stock] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Stock] )
            && 'Table'[EQ]    = EARLIER ( 'Table'[EQ] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis for response I appreciate it. However EARLIER function is still greyed out and not taking the query. Could you please explain this?

Comment: I don’t see a snap but are you trying to define measures rather than calculated columns? EARLIER doesn’t make sense if these are measures.

Comment: Thank you Alexis for helping out I got the error and now using Calculated columns but for the FirstDateOfRange34 it is showing error "<pi>A circular dependency was detected: New folder[FirstDateRange34].</pi>" Could you please help me out? I am sorry I am nagging too much but wants to learn

Comment: Does it help if you write `FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), ... )` instead of `FILTER ( 'Table', ... )` in each one?

Comment: Will try and let you know Thanks

Comment: Hi Alexis I have been able to run this in Calculated Columns. Now the issue is it is not solving ATR34 column having more than a millions rows. I am getting an error of insufficient memory. I have upgraded the RAM from 16GB to 32GB still it is utilizing 99% RAM before giving an error without solving it. Can you please guide me how to proceed further in this scenario?